# Seleccionar todos lo elementos de un Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero ocultar unos div dependiendo de los id.

```
var id = productId;
var idproducto = [723,715];

  if( id == idproducto[0]){
    $('.items-producto').css('display','none');
  }
```

lo intente así pero solo me oculta el primero es decir el "723".

la idea es ocultarlos todos, pero no se como seleccionar todo el arreglo.

Gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tienes que iterar sobre el arreglo, al usar [0] solo estas diciendo que seleccione el primer elemento del arreglo

```
var id = productId;
var idproducto = [723,715];

idproducto.forEach(producto => {

   if( id == producto){
     $('.items-producto').css('display','none');
   }
})
```

Comment: Cabe mencionar que si el OP realiza este código no funcionará, en primera porque no se sabe si `productId` es un arreglo o un string y en segunda si utiliza  esta línea `$('.items-producto').css('display','none');` se ocultarán los divs en la primera iteración ya que va a tomar todos los elementos que tengan esa clase, caso contrario si lo hace con su `id`.

Comment: porque un voto negativo?, si esta respuesta me funciono

Comment: @DANIELFERNANDOSALINAS 

Answer (score 0):

Indicas que quieres que se oculten todos los divs con `id` que se encuentren dentro de este arreglo -> `var idproducto = [723,715];` entonces supongo que `productId` es un arreglo que contiene algunos de estos valores que sean iguales a `idproducto = [723,715];`, sabiendo esto creo un arreglo para ejemplificar, utilizamos [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) para recorrer el arreglo `idproducto` y utilizamos dos elementos como callback, el `index` y el `element`, el `index` es el índice en el que se encuentra el elemento y el `element` es el valor del elemento, después de esto validamos si el `id`(que sabemos que es un arreglo y obtenemos su valor de esta forma `id[index] -> id[0], id[1]`, etc) es igual al elemento del `idproducto`, si lo es por medio de [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) seleccionamos por `id` el DIV a ocultar, si lo haces con la clase se van a ocultar todos desde la primera iteración, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let productId = [723,715,740];


var id = productId;
var idproducto = [723,715,750];

idproducto.forEach(function(element,index){

  
  if( id[index] === element){
    $(`#${element}`).css('display','none');
  }

console.log(id[index])
console.log(element);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="715" class="items-producto">Div1</div>
<div id="723" class="items-producto">Div2</div>
<div id="740" class="items-producto">Div3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = productId;
var idproducto = [723,715];

for(i=0;i<=idproducto.length;i++){
      if( id == idproducto[i]){
        $('.items-producto').css('display','none');
      }
}
```

Comment: Hola. agrega por favor una explicación del código, ¿como ayudaría a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta?, revisar [answer]., saludos.